# О значении приставки ПРО в глаголе "проистечь"?

Tags: семантика, морфемика, приставка

По словарю глагол ***проистечь*** используется для обозначения  **причины** (произойти вследствие чего-либо), но почему именно такое значение? Обычно **[приставка ПРО](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42)**  связана с направленностью действия **сквозь/через** предмет в пространстве или во времени. Откуда же берется причина и какое **истолкование**  здесь возможно (в соответствии со словарным значением приставки)?

**Нацкорпус**

*Ошибка **проистекает** из того факта, что в Греции одна и та же фраза может обозначать конкретное и абстрактное»*

*Я полагаю, что страсть олигарха платить за культуру **проистекает** еще и из затаенного комплекса вины.*

**Словарь:**

**ПРОИСТЕЧЬ,** -течёт, -текут; проистёк, -текла, -ло; проистекший; св. Возникнуть, произойти **вследствие чего-л.** Разногласия проистекли из нежелания понять друг друга. Проистекать, -ает; нсв.

**ИСТЕЧЬ,** -теку, -течёшь, -текут; истёк, -текла, -ло; истёкший и (устар.) истекший; св. 1. Книжн. =**Вытечь** (о жидкости). Из скалы истёк поток. Из сосуда истекла вода. 2. **Окончиться**, прийти к концу (о сроке, времени). Срок договора истёк. Со дня отъезда истекли три недели. **3. чем. Выделить какую-л. жидкость в большом количестве.** И. потом. Ствол сосны истёк смолой. И. кровью, слезами (ослабеть, изнемочь от потери крови, от плача). Истекать, -аю, -аешь; нсв

Answer (score 3):

А кто сказал, что семантика приставки всегда должна чувствоваться в любом значении любого слова, включая и переносное?

***Истечь*** - это вытечь откуда-то (Ожегов, Ушаков, МАС, БАС). Тут чувствуется пространственное значение приставки ***из-*** (выделение, появление откуда-то в примерах типа *извлечь, излиться, изгнать*).

Однако, есть и переносные употребления, например *истечь* в значении "*окончиться*". Так вот, разве в *истечь* в смысле "*окончиться*" чувствуется значение приставки ***из-***? Что  получится тогда: *окончиться из чего-то, откуда-то*. Нет, ничего этого нет. В переносном употреблении деривационное значение морфемы нейтрализуется.

***Проистечь*** - то же самое по словарям, что и истечь (излиться, истечь откуда-нибудь). Это прямое, "физическое", но устарелое значение. Допустим. Ну и где в *"проистечь"* в смысле *"истечь"* значение приставки ***про-***?

У ***про-*** много значений, наиболее близкое к нашему случаю это "направленность сквозь, через что-то" (прорубить, пробурить, прорезать, протечь). Однако словарь ***не толкует*** слово *проистечь* как ***про + истечь***, то есть ***течь откуда-то*** + ***через что*-то**.

Иначе говоря, *проистечь* в литературном языке - это *только* истечь, *а не истечь + **про-***, то есть истечь, ***проникнув, пробурив собою что-то.***

Получается, что даже в исходном, "*водном*" значении глагола *проистечь* значение ***про-*** не фиксируется, то есть этот морф формально есть, но к смыслу слова вроде как ничего и не добавляет, он семантически пуст.

Второе значение *проистечь* - это возникнуть по причине чего-либо, то есть тут переносное значение, возникшее, по-видимому, на основе метафорического переосмысления основного значения. Где тут значение ***про-*** и почему оно должно тут быть?

Ковыряешь так морфемный состав слова в переносном употреблении и понимаешь, что это переносное употребление никак не вытекает из банального словообразовательного синтеза морфем, составляющих слово, на то оно и переносное.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня (за внимание к теме). Мне 
 ведь никто не отвечает, никто со мной не разговаривает, вот 
 только если вы...  А мои вопросы считаются  риторическими.  
 Поэтому мне грустно и одиноко))
```

**Мое мнение**

Я всегда **считываю значение** слов с морфем.  Хобби такое!  Вот и здесь тоже, а оно никак не считывается!  Стала искать  информацию **в Сети**, там ж все есть. Вот такой ответ нашелся (шутка, наверное):

1. **[Чем отличается значение слов истекает и проистекает?](https://otvet.mail.ru/answer/2048826457)**

*Развиваем **пространственное воображение**. Представьте абстрактный сосуд, из которого вытекает/истекает поток (жидкость или время).  Это значение глагола ***истекать*** и приставки ***ИЗ***.  А теперь на пути потока встречается другой предмет,  так что движение происходит сквозь этот предмет (приставка ***ПРО)***. А что это за предмет? Это **причина чего-либо**.  Проверяем по словарю:  ИСТЕЧЬ, св. 1. Книжн. = Вытечь (о жидкости). 2. Окончиться, прийти к концу (о сроке, времени). ПРОИСТЕЧЬ,  св. Возникнуть, произойти вследствие чего-л.*

2. **[А это из вопроса на БВ](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4348586-russkaja-pristavka-pro-kak-to-sootnositsja-s-grecheskoj-proto.html#answer12334898)** (люди тоже ищут)

*Они **родственные**. Было праиндоевропейское ***pro*** - "перед чем-то, сперва, до", от него в русском появилась приставка "про-", в греческом и латыни - тоже приставки "pro-" (от которых возникло "proto"), а в английском, например - from.*

3. Думаю про приставку  ***proto***, и вот нахожу такой **[ответ](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2440470-chto-oznachaet-pristavka-proto--etimologija.html)**:

*Греческая лексема **πρώτος (protos)** на русский переводится как «первый, главный»   Отсюда и три основных значения приставки ПРОТО-.   1) со значениями **первоначальности, истоков** того, что названо существительным производящим, например, алфавит => протоалфави́т (система письма, породившая все алфавиты мира);  В данном значении приставка ПРОТО- синонимична приставке ***ПРА-***. Есть, например, слова: праалфавит; праистория;*

4. Может, ***ПРО*** — это усеченная приставка ***proto***  со значением первоначальности,  как приставка ***ПРА***.

Comment: про указывает на прямую причину, в то время как ис-/ из- указывают на косвенную, на способ. Например: пробежать - значит бежать ранее, сперва(то есть начало) там, но сейчас находится в другом месте и уже не обязательно бежать; избежать - уже образное, не связанное с бегом, а связанное с подобием избегания, то есть уже семантическая приставка, сделать что-то исходя из идеи бега, при этом не обязательно бегая, даже скорее всего не бегая. То есть проистекать, связано с течением, с неразрывностью течения и указание на связь причины и следствия чего-то.

Comment: проистечь же вообще указывает на следствие: из этого может проистечь следующее... А истекать не обязательно связано с причиной и следствием - "время истекло", некое событие ставится в подчинение идее времени, причём само временем может не является, то есть не проистекает из времени или временного срока. Время истекло, урок окончен. Время проистекло, урок окончен - уже не скажешь.

Comment: То есть истекло не всегда заменишь на проистекло, а вот проистекло часто можно заменить на истекло или вытекло.

Comment: Спасибо, мне нравятся ваши комментарии. И  они чем-то похожи на ответ из мейл.ру https://otvet.mail.ru/answer/2048826457 А про латинскую приставку proto что думаете?  Кстати, о вашем примере "избежать".  Я решила, что там должен  быть корень ИЗБЕЖ. И точно, проверила по словарю. Вот оно, правильное словообразование (формант  здесь, а не корень!) А почему вы на стали давать ответ, а только комментарии. Впрочем, у меня есть версия (я ведь как бы немного психолог))

Comment: @Буратино Можно вопрос офтоп?  Какое значение добавляет суффикс ИВ к слову предикат? Это латинский по происхождению суффикс?  Или лучше задать вопрос, а вы на него ответите? Тема интересна не только мне.